# Вызов одной процедуры посредством клика по разным кнопкам

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Есть три кнопки на Windows форме

[image: Кнопки на форме]

Есть у меня обработчик события по кнопке "Сложить":

```
    System::Void Project1::Main::button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    String^ input_collection;
    std::string string_value ;
    std::vector<double> collection_vec;
    double num;
    ...
 }
```

Как к нему привязать щелчок по остальным двум кнопкам, чтобы при этом при обращении к конкретной кнопке она передавала в процедуру некое `enum` значение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
... AddButton_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    Execute(Operation::Add);
}

... SubtractButton_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    Execute(Operation::Subtract);
}

Execute(Operation operation)
{
    // тут вычисления
}
```

---

Надеюсь, вы понимаете, что C++ и C++/CLI - это **разные** языки? И если вы хотите освоить первый, то даже не касайтесь второй. И забудьте про сочетание C++ и WinForms.

---

Зачем вы смешали строки разных видов?

```
String^ input_collection;
std::string string_value ;
```

Вы влипли в WinForms. Значит используете C++/CLI. Значит, будьте последовательны до конца и всегда используйте *управляемые* (managed) типы. То есть `String ^` и т. п. Обратите внимание на значок `^` - управляемая ссылка.

---

```
std::vector<double>
```

Аналогично. В .NET есть богатый набор коллекций. См. [System.Collections.Generic](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic?view=net-5.0). Вместо `std::vector` возьмите `List<T>`.

Comment: Я все прекрасно понимаю, ситуация университетская: заставляют так мешать. Зачем? Не понимаю сам.